# Shell Script for combining 3 files

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have 3 files with below data

```
$cat File1.txt
Apple,May
Orange,June
Mango,July

$cat File2.txt
Apple,Jan
Grapes,June

$cat File3.txt
Apple,March
Mango,Feb
Banana,Dec
```

I require the below output file.

```
$Output_file.txt
Apple,May|Jan|March
Orange,June
Mango,July|Feb
Grapes,June
Banana,Dec
```

Requirement here is the take out the first column and then common data in column 1 in each file need to be searched and second column needs to be "|" separated. If there is no common column, then same needs to be printed in the output file.

I have tried putting this in a while loop, but it takes time as the file size increase. Wanted a simple solution using shell script.

Comment: The shell script will not be a simple solution.

Comment: Hmmm so you suggest to go with a while loop itself? Was just looking for some simpler solution using shell. No other option I can think of other than shell for now.

Comment: I would look at doing this in a more capable language.

Comment: One certainly *could* do this in shell (I think Ignacio is overestimating the difficulty), but "here are my requirements, please write a program for me" is not what we do here. Have you encountered a specific problem you can ask about, or do you have a specific question about the language and its capabilities?

Comment: Frankly, showing us your slow `while`-loop-based approach would make this a much stronger question -- that gives us an idea of what order of magnitude of performance enhancements are still cheaply available without changing to a different language. (If your original code was invoking external tools or subshells inside the loop, that leaves much more room for improvement than if it was bumping up against the limits of the bash interpreter itself).

Comment: got you point. I will edit my question and post the while loop that is tried.

Comment: (if you *are* already sticking to pure native bash, the next place to go might be moving to ksh93 -- a much faster interpreter with a quite similar language, making it relatively easy to adopt).

Comment: @Programmer, ...how are you actually evaluating performance here? The answer you accepted will scale badly as the number of distinct fruits increases, as it launches a set of subshells for each. (It also reads the input files n+1 times -- once to list the fruits, and another time for each distinct fruit, since it's reading all the input to filter for the individual item).

Comment: I have max row of 1000.

Comment: ...and how many distinct fruits in those 1000 rows? If you had, say, 800 fruits over 1000 rows, the performance impact of running a new pipeline for each one would be substantial.

Comment: I understood your case, but for now I am able to run it faster than the while loop. I will consider your script as well and the awk replacement given in the below command to verify the performance of the script.

Comment: Faster than *which* while loop? Than the original while loop you never showed us, or the while loop in my answer? Mind you, what would be faster than both (and quite easy to implement) is an answer that's all just one `awk` call, not using any shell loops at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
#!/bin/bash
for FRUIT in $( cat "$@" | cut -d "," -f 1 | sort | uniq )
do
    echo -ne "${FRUIT},"
    awk -F "," "\$1 == \"$FRUIT\" {printf(\"%s|\",\$2)}" "$@" | sed 's/.$/\'$'\n/'
done
```

Run it as :

```
$ ./script.sh File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt
```

Comment: `cat $*` won't ever work with a filename with spaces. Use `"$@"` instead.

Comment: `"$@"`, with the quotes. Without them, `$@` has the same problems as `$*`.

Comment: Thanks Gautam, the only challenge I face here is with the output. I get all the separator as "|". I need first separator as ",", rest all "|".

Comment: You could probably have `awk` take over all the work of the `grep | cut | awk | sed` pipeline, btw; it's perfectly capable of doing filtering itself. If you use `awk -F,`, for example, then your field would become `$2`, so you don't need the `cut`. And if you use `awk -v fruit="$FRUIT" '$1 == fruit { printf "%s|", $2)}'`, then your code block will only run when the first field is the fruit, so you don't need the `grep` either.

Comment: @Gautam, your update that includes `\n` in the sed replacement string is limited to GNU sed, and will not work on platforms that use other dialects (BSD, macOS, Solaris, etc).

Comment: `"/$FRUIT/"` is searching for the fruit *everywhere*, not just in the first column (and it also allows injection attacks, where content in your data can run arbitrary code; consider if `FRUIT='./ && system("rm -rf ~") && /.'`). If there's a city of Applevale in column 2, you don't want that to match for "Apple"; the search should be an exact-match only, and in the first column only.

Answer (score 1):

A purely native-bash solution (calling no external tools, and thus limited only by the performance constraints of bash itself) might look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
case $BASH_VERSION in ''|[123].*) echo "ERROR: Bash 4 or newer required" >&2; exit 1;; esac

declare -A items=( )
for file in "$@"; do
  while IFS=, read -r key value; do
    items[$key]+="|$value"
  done <"$file"
done

for key in "${!items[@]}"; do
  value=${items[$key]}
  printf '%s,%s\n' "$key" "${value#'|'}"
done
```

...called as `./yourscript File1.txt File2.txt File3.txt`

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly easy done with a single `awk` command:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {a[$1] = a[$1] (a[$1] == "" ? "" : "|") $2}
END {for (i in a) print i, a[i]}' File{1,2,3}.txt
```

```
Orange,June
Banana,Dec
Apple,May|Jan|March
Grapes,June
Mango,July|Feb
```

If you want output in the same order as strings appear in original files then use this `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} !($1 in a) {b[++n] = $1}
{a[$1] = a[$1] (a[$1] == "" ? "" : "|") $2}
END {for (i=1; i<=n; i++) print b[i], a[b[i]]}' File{1,2,3}.txt
```

```
Apple,May|Jan|March
Orange,June
Mango,July|Feb
Grapes,June
Banana,Dec
```